# Internet on EC2 based Wireguard not working

Tags: ubuntu, networking, amazon-ec2, vpn, wireguard

Summary:

I have created a Wireguard VPN server on an AWS EC2 instance.
From the VPN client I can connect to the VPN correctly and ping the VPN server.
When attempting to access the internet from the client I am unable to get any responses from external servers.

Full technical details:

I have created an Ubuntu 20.04 EC2 instance on amazon EC2 with a public elastic IP. The Security  Group associated with the instance allows for the following Inbound Rules (and a blanket 0.0.0.0/0 outbound rules):

```
Custom TCP  TCP 41194   0.0.0.0/0       Wireguard listen port
SSH         TCP 22      <my_known_ip>   SSH
Custom UDP  UDP 41194   0.0.0.0/0       Wireguard listen port
```

The Wireguard configuration is then as follows on the server:

```
[Interface]
Address = 192.168.2.1
PrivateKey = <priv_key>
ListenPort = 41194
PostUp   = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
# NAME OF CLIENT
PublicKey = <pub_key>
AllowedIPs = 192.168.2.3/32
```

On the server I then also configure the OS's firewall using the following commands(done as root user):

```
ufw allow from 192.168.2.0/24
ufw allow 41194/any
ufw allow 22/any
ufw enable
```

I also enable the server to forward IPv4 traffic by updating `/etc/sysctl.conf` to have the following set:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

And ensure the above takes affect using `sysctl -p`

Once this is done I start the Wireguard service on the server (`wg-quick up wg0`).

On the client I then use the following configuration to connect to the VPN server:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <priv_key_of_client>
ListenPort = 21841
Address = 192.168.2.3/32
DNS = 192.168.2.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = <pub_key_of_server>
AllowedIPs = 192.168.2.1/24, 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = <public_ip_of_ec2_instance>:41194
```

And once starting the VPN on the client, it connects successfully and from the client I can successfully ping the VPN server (`ping 192.168.2.1`). But from the client I can not access any other external server (ie no internet access).

The following debugging steps are all performed on the VPN server itself:

I ensured that on the wirguard server itself I can access the internet (`curl -L google.com` returns correctly).

Watching the network traffic on the Wireguard interface using `tcpdump -n -i wg0` I see that all the connections attempted by the client (ip `192.168.2.3`) do not ever get a return from the third party server. ie the following SYN [S] request is seen to be sent out but no corresponding [S.] is seen to come back. eg:

```
09:04:36.133008 IP 192.168.2.3.57624 >  172.217.170.4.80: Flags [S], seq 1394306065, win 65535, options [mss 1380,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 1126938286 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
```

The same can be seen when performing a tcpdump on the default `ens5` interface that the wireguard server uses. So the request from the client is being seen by the wireguard server on `wg0`, this request is then forwarded onto `ens5` and out to the 3rd party server (google.com) but no corresponding reply can be seen to any of the SYN packets that are sent out.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my own issues. My `ufw` was not setup correctly to do the NAT'ing correctly.

So I added the following to `/etc/ufw/before.rules`:

```
# NAT table rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

# Forward traffic through eth0 - Change to match you out-interface
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -o ens5 -j MASQUERADE

# don't delete the 'COMMIT' line or these nat table rules won't
# be processed
COMMIT
```

Then restarted `ufw` with `ufw disable` and `ufw enable` and internet now works correctly from the VPN client.